# Java based web application running very slows twice or thice in a day at certain hours

Tags: java, angularjs, spring, oracle, plsql

**Problem Description**: We have a web application which is used by 200-300 people per day. The application slows down twice or thrice in a day at certain hours changing it's home page load time from 6-7 seconds to 11-13 seconds. This application is deployed on JBoss AS 7.2. There are 4-5 other applications which are deployed on the same Jobss on the same instance(port number). These application are web services(REST & SOAP webservices which are used by other applications of same company which I am not aware about) that use the same database as the Main application which is having slowness issues. The application is built with the following technology stack:

- Frontend: Angular JS, Angular UI, JqueryUI, JSON
- Backend: Spring REST controllers, Java 7, JDBC
- Database: Oracle 11g, PL SQL

It's been only 4 months since the application response time as soared up. We had a production release 4 months ago, in which lots of data filtering is done on the basis of certain parameters. This code is implemented in PL/SQL. Also some filtering of data is done in front end. The response time has increased after this release. (Note: During this period number of users and data has also increased by a significant amount)

So far I have tried to improve the performance by minimising Javascript files changing 2.8 MB of DOM downloaded Content to just 1.2 MB. I have also optimised some of the queries which are being used for data filtering. I have been able to bring homepage load time down to average 9-10 seconds. Which is still quite more than client's expectation.

I would like to know how to tackle this kind of issues and what all things should I bear in mind which might have been causing this problem.

At present production jvm configurations are xms: 64 MB, xmx: 256 MB. will changing increasing the memory help? 
Should I remove the PLSQL codeand write Java code and use multithreading?
During the peak time CPU usage gets quite high around 85-95 percent. The main tables are used by many applications(cron job which calls java program to send email notifications) What can be done about it?

Comment: You will have to measure which component of the system slows it down, e.g. how high is the load on the data base commonly and during the slow times, processor load and memory usage on the web server, network traffic etc. This will be the first step to locate the culprit.

Comment: are you sure it's an application performance issue ? if the hick up repeats itself, it may be due to GC bumping in. Start timing the queryes and perform some profile using the browser's network inspect (on Chrome just press F12).

Comment: Agree with @UweAllner, these measurements are essential to narrowing down your suspects.  You can use JBoss' server access logs to determine if there is heavier traffic during slow-down periods. Also, if your shop has good change management practices, review what changed in the deployments when you first started noticing a slow-down, could be server configuration change or added deployment from another team.  Monitor database session activity during the heavy times see if the sessions spike during that time.

Comment: @UweAllner Thanks! The CPU usage on the DB server is usually 85-95 percent and we do not have statics of CPU usage of back then, when the application performance was normal.

Comment: Be sure that you're not creating too many connections to the Database. There is a vicious cycle where when the Database becomes slow the connection pool attempts to create new JDBC connections which makes the situation even worst. Your connection pool should be well sized and that size should be reasonable small. For example min=max=10 times the number of physical cores on the DB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed this issue now. As per comments and suggestions, I timed queries to database, checked database logs & monitored daily CPU usage. I did same for application server and analysed using jvisualvm.

I did a bit of everything like minimising static content, optimise queries, remove unnecessary logging, The significant change however has come from changing JVM tuning (heap size -xms:1024M, -xmx:1536M & permGen: 512M and other things). The performance has now improved a lot changing average home page(after login time) to 4 to 5 seconds(from 10-13 seconds).

There are still chances of improvement from Database point of view. Some queries and PL SQL blocks have to be optimized. But it's nonetheless quite better than before. [image: The image displaying latest performance]